# Stream live data into Google cloud pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to connect Oracle database and get live data stream into Google cloud pub/sub?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is yes, but the longer more detailed answer includes making some assumptions like, when you say **stream**, do you literally mean **stream** or do you mean **batch updating every minute**?

Asking this question because there are huge implications depending on the answer meaning, if you require a true **streaming** solution, the only one is to bolt an Oracle product on top of your database called [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html).  This product is costly both in dollars and in engineering effort.

If a near real time solution is suitable to you, then you can use any of the following solutions:

- [NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/)

Or

- [Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/)
- [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi)

With either plain SQL or using a streaming framework like [Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) or [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

Or any other orchestration platform that can run queries on a timer.  At the end of the day, all you need is something that can do `select * from table where last_update > now() - threshold`, generate an *event* for each delta, and then publish all the deltas to PubSub.

Comment: Yet one more approach is to use Triggers and Queue tables.  In summary, have a trigger write the delta to a table, and have a process consume from that table generating events to publish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see a provided template at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#gcstexttocloudpubsub that reads from Google Cloud Storage Text to Cloud Pub/Sub. You should be able to change the code that reads from storage to read from your database instead.

Answer (score 0):

yes. I tried as part of 1 POC. Using triggers capture the changed records from Oracle, using a Cursor convert those into .txt file with data in JSON format.Prepare batch script to read the data and include Publish command inside the batch file to push the data through cloud PubSub. This is the overall flow

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Change data Capture(CDC) tools like [Debezium](https://github.com/debezium/debezium) that detect your db changes in real time.

Docs: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/operations/debezium-server.html

With Spring boot: https://www.baeldung.com/debezium-intro